# EditText and instanceof not working?

Tags: android

Why is the EditText instanceof call not working but TextView instanceof call is?

Can I solve this with generics or other better way?

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
...
    @Override
    public void updateView() {
       updateField(noteEditText, vault.getNote());
       updateField(categoryTextView, category.getName());
    }

    private void updateField(View current, String data) {
        if(current instanceof EditText && data.equals(((EditText) current).getText())) {
            ((EditText) current).setText(data); 
        } else if(current instanceof TextView && data.equals(((TextView) current).getText())) {
            ((TextView) current).setText(data);
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: basically because you ignored the `&&`. `instanceOf` works fine, but the way you get string from it is wrong. `((EditText) current).getText()` returns a `Editable ` object, not string. so **one condition of operator and is not true**. `((EditText) current).getText().toString()` is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EditText.getText() does not return a `String` but an `Editable` object, this is the reason why the first check always fails. Just call `toString()` on the result of `((Editable)current).getText()`:

```
if(current instanceof EditText && data.equals(((EditText) current).getText().toString())) {
    ((EditText) current).setText(data);
} else if(current instanceof TextView && data.equals(((TextView) current).getText().toString())) {
    ((TextView) current).setText(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
try {
  ((EditText) current).setText(data);
} catch (Exception e){
  // Not an EditText
  try {
    ((TextView) current).setText(data);
  } catch (Exception e){
    // Not a textView
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not use exceptions in place of if-else blocks...!